# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' when using Apache and ModWSGI in CentOS 8

Tags: python, apache, flask, centos, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask application that I want to deploy using Apache/ Httpd in CentOS 7. I have developed a Virtual Environment for the project and when I use the development server to run the project, everything runs well. However, when I try to start the project and the venv using Apache Virtual Host, I get this error in the Httpd error log file.

```
Current thread 0x00007fcf20e0e540 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/local/bin'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local/bin'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local/bin'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local/bin'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local/bin'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/bin/lib64/python39.zip',
    '/usr/local/bin/lib64/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/bin/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fcf20e0e540 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I have tried to create a new Virtual Env but that gives the same error. I have checked the versions of both Python and Venv and both are 3.9.17. In short, the project/ venv runs fine when I run it using python main.py, but it gives the ModuleNotFound Error when I run the same project and venv in httpd using ModWSGI